# Can i assign value to a variable in an application at runtime through a text file and then set that value to permanent

Tags: vb.net, runtime, assign

sir, i have no idea how the code will look, but i want it to assign a value after reading from a text file and then store it for further use even if the text file is not there, but without using any external storage like registry, disk, ram. It should store the value in itself and do like this:-
dim variable1, variable2 as string
if file.exists("text.txt")
     read the text
      store the text in variable 1
else
      variable2 = variable1
end if

on the basis of variable1
some action
on the basis of variable2
some action

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So, if the new value can't be persisted to disk, how would it possibly retain the value between reboots? Does the Internet count as an external device?  What about a LAN? Perhaps you can explain the scenario more precisely...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a value permanent without storing it anywhere. You will need any external storage. There is not another solution. Dot.

There is nothing like "itself". Itself is memory, and when the application stops memory is clear and the value is not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, your logic was hard to follow.  What about something like:

```
Private mVariable1 = Nothing
Private mVariable2 As String = "Something"
Private mFilePath As String = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")
Private mFileSpec As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(mFilePath, "textfile.txt")

' dgp rev 3/13/2012
Private ReadOnly Property Variable1 As String
    Get
        If mVariable1 Is Nothing Then
            If System.IO.File.Exists(mFileSpec) Then
                Try
                    Dim sr = New StreamReader(mFileSpec)
                    mVariable1 = sr.ReadToEnd
                    sr.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    mVariable1 = "error"
                End Try
            Else
                mVariable1 = mVariable2
            End If
        End If
        Return mVariable1
    End Get

End Property
```

The Variable will be initialized on the first reference with either the text file or a hard coded value if the file does not exist.  Of course, nothing is persistent once the program is closed.  That is where I get a little fuzzy on your requirements.